# Find png files in folder structure and map them to Photoshop groups and layers

Tags: python, image, file-system

I've created a heavily problematic code that works.

Summary: It looks through a folder structure, for png files and tries to replicate this structure in Photoshop. Files are mapped layers and Folders to Groups. I am using `comtypes` to access Photoshop and create the groups and layers.

The issue I faced with, is that you can't access Photoshop Layer Objects directly (instead you have to go through the whole structure). E.g. to access

```
new
 |
 -- folder
        |-- sub_folder
                     |-- random_file
```

in order to access the random_file, you have to access new, then folder, then `sub_folder`!

The following code works and it was developed through an intense mental state of concentration (and some trial and error). I believe it's horrendous though! As I am trying to learn how to be a better programmer and learn from the best, I though to ask your help: Can somebody guide me in order to re-factor this beast? What can I do better and what's the way to go with?

```py
# Algorithm (?):
# ---------
# Starting from given top folder structure .
# traverse downwards and create
# photoshop groups named as the folders
# import all the png files under this
# as linked layers and name them accordingly
# traverse another layer deeper
# and do the same

# Import layers from Misc as Background and Shadow

os.chdir(ROOT_PATH + '/Misc')
import_all_pngs_as_layers(new_doc, new_doc, ROOT_PATH + '/Misc')
os.chdir(ROOT_PATH)  # Revert the working path

duplicate = False
subdir = False

for root, dd, ff in os.walk('.'):
    path = root.split(os.sep)
    if not os.path.basename(root) == '.':  # ignore parent
        if os.path.dirname(root).replace(".\\", "") in IGNORED_DIRS:
            pass
        elif not os.path.dirname(root) == '.' and not os.path.dirname(
                root).replace(".\\", "") in IGNORED_DIRS:
            # print('I am a subdir {} of the dir {}'.format(
            # os.path.basename(root),
            # os.path.dirname(root).replace(".\\", "")))
            create_group_named(
                new_doc, os.path.basename(root),
                new_doc.LayerSets(os.path.dirname(root).replace(".\\", "")))
        elif not os.path.basename(root) in IGNORED_DIRS:
            # print("Create TOP LEVEL layer group named",
            # os.path.basename(root))
            create_group_named(
                new_doc,
                os.path.basename(root))  # Create a group named 'subdir'
    if len(ff) > 1:
        for filename in ff:
            if filename.endswith('.png'):
                for item in GROUPED_LAYERS:
                    # print(item)
                    # print(item in filename)
                    if item in filename:
                        # print(
                        # 'lets create a group {} and put the layer{} under it in folder {}'
                        # .format(item, filename, os.path.basename(root)))
                        os.chdir(os.path.realpath(root))

                        try:
                            new_doc.LayerSets(
                                os.path.basename(root)).LayerSets(item)
                        except:
                            ng = create_group_named(
                                new_doc, item,
                                new_doc.LayerSets(os.path.basename(root)))
                            create_layer_from_file(
                                new_doc, filename, ng,
                                os.path.realpath(filename))

                        else:
                            # print(new_doc.LayerSets(os.path.basename(root)))
                            create_layer_from_file(
                                new_doc, filename,
                                new_doc.LayerSets(
                                    os.path.basename(root)).LayerSets(item),
                                os.path.realpath(filename))

                        duplicate = True
                        os.chdir(ROOT_PATH)
                if duplicate:
                    pass
                    duplicate = False
                else:
                    os.chdir(os.path.realpath(root))
                    # print('Rest files import as layers {} under {}'.format(
                    # filename, os.path.basename(root)))

                    if os.path.basename(
                            root) in IGNORED_DIRS or os.path.dirname(
                                root).replace(".\\", "") in IGNORED_DIRS:
                        pass
                    elif not os.path.dirname(root) == '.':
                        # print('layer {} on main group {} on group {}'
                        # .format(filename, os.path.dirname(root).replace(".\\",""), os.path.basename(root)))
                        create_layer_from_file(
                            new_doc, filename,
                            new_doc.LayerSets(
                                os.path.dirname(root).replace(
                                    ".\\", "")).LayerSets(
                                        os.path.basename(root)),
                            os.path.realpath(filename))
                    else:
                        create_layer_from_file(
                            new_doc, filename,
                            new_doc.LayerSets[os.path.basename(root)],
                            os.path.realpath(filename))
                    os.chdir(ROOT_PATH)
            else:
                pass
```

For completeness here's the rest of the program:

```py
import comtypes.client as ct

psApp = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')
new_doc = psApp.Documents.Add(600, 800, 72, "new-psb-test", 2, 1, 1)

# they are ignored as those are the directories on the root level
# and I explicitly import them and their layers before the loop
IGNORED_DIRS = ['Misc', 'Wheel_Merged']

# If the files (inside the group/folder Accessories)
# include the following in their names then they need to be 
# sub- grouped under that name: e.g. Grille_01, 22_Grille, Grille0 all need to be
# layers under the Group named Grille 
GROUPED_LAYERS = ['Body_Side', 'Grille']

def create_group_named(doc, layer_set, under=''):
    """ Create a New LayerSet (aka Group) in the Photoshop
        document (doc).
    Args:
    doc (obj): The Photoshop Document Instance
    under (obj): The Group Object Instance
    (e.g. if you want a subgroup under Lights then give that
    object as a under name)
    layer_set (str): The name of the new Layer Set
    Returns:
    new_layer_set (obj): The LayerSet (Group) Object
    """
    if not under:  # add a top level group
        new_layer_set = doc.layerSets.Add()
    else:  # add subgroup
        new_layer_set = under.LayerSets.Add()
    new_layer_set.name = layer_set
    return new_layer_set

def paste_file_as_linked_layer(path):
    """ Import a file as a photoshop (smart) linked layer
    Args:
    path(str): The exact path of the image including extension
    Returns:
    whatever execute action returns (TBC)
    """
    idPlc = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Plc ")

    desc11 = ct.CreateObject("Photoshop.ActionDescriptor")
    idIdnt = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Idnt")
    desc11.putInteger(idIdnt, 2)

    # Open the file (path)
    idnull = psApp.charIDToTypeID("null")
    desc11.putPath(idnull, path)

    # set its type as a linked payer
    idLnkd = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Lnkd")
    desc11.putBoolean(idLnkd, True)

    idFTcs = psApp.charIDToTypeID("FTcs")
    idQCSt = psApp.charIDToTypeID("QCSt")
    idQcsa = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Qcsa")
    desc11.putEnumerated(idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa)

    idOfst = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Ofst")
    desc12 = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.ActionDescriptor')
    idHrzn = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Hrzn")
    idRlt = psApp.charIDToTypeID("#Rlt")
    desc12.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idRlt, 0)
    idVrtc = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Vrtc")
    idRlt = psApp.charIDToTypeID("#Rlt")
    desc12.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idRlt, 0)
    idOfst = psApp.charIDToTypeID("Ofst")
    # put the object in an offset space of 0,0
    desc11.putObject(idOfst, idOfst, desc12)

    # 'return' of the function
    # is the placement of the linked layer
    f = psApp.executeAction(idPlc, desc11, 3)

def create_layer_from_file(doc, layer_name, layer_set, path):
    """ Create new Layer from File nested under a LayerSet
    Args:
    doc (obj): The working Photoshop file
    layer_name (str): The given name for the Layer
    layer_set (obj): the LayerSet object that the Layer is nested under
    path (str): the full Path of the file (including the extension)
    Returns:
    """
    psApp.activeDocument = doc
    layer = layer_set.artLayers.Add()
    layer.name = layer_name  # Rename Layer
    doc.activeLayer = layer  # Select Layer

    paste_file_as_linked_layer(os.path.realpath(path).replace('\\', '/'))

    return layer
```

Comment: @wizofe your code is __not__ horrible, sure there's some formatting that would improve readability, and [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) would allow for extending into a full command line utility, aside from those nits it's looking okay for the most part. In particular, those `if os.path.basename(...).replace(...` lines maybe easier to debug later if it where a convenience function. As for accessing `random_file` within `sub_folder`, if ya don't like nesting, maybe try an intermediate structure to organize things the way ya like, eg. `pandas`, `dict`, etc.

Comment: @S0AndS0: That sounds like the start of a nice answer!

Comment: Thanks @S0AndS0. Indeed I need to use `argparse` as I did in a similar tool I developed after this :) 

Can you give me examples for the terms:
- 'convenience function': How I can implement one for the `if os.path.basename(...).replace(...)`?
- My big trouble was to create such an 'intermediate structure' for my pre-existing folder structure/schema. An example on that would be very awesome (I am happy to see one both using `pandas` and a `dict` Thanks again :)

Comment: @Graipher some may call it _foreshadowing_ ;-)... @wizofe most welcome and I'm glad that it seems to be helping so far, one thing my answer here does __not__ cover, searching and accessing some `random_file` object, is something that I kinda covered over on [math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3171877/657433). Though there'd be _**some**_ modification I believe the resulting code maybe shorter than what's demonstrated there. Hint `first_to_compute` would instead contain a search `str`ing or `list`, maybe _`walk`ing_ in a _`yield`ing_ fashion; bonus points for readable recursiveness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent *sometime* with the [`code`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219028/197446) you've currently posted @wizofe, I'm not sure if it'll ever be the same again...

> Side note; I heard it rumored that the character limits are *just a bit* more relaxed than on other sub-stacks... or in other-words this may get a bit verbose, or in other-other-words it could be *another one of those posts* so a snack and drink is a solid choice.

#### `utils_photoshop/__init__.py`

> I didn't have insight as to how you where organizing code so I'm making up file and directory names for later *pseudo-`import`ing*.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import comtypes.client as ct


__license__ = """
See selection from author of question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219028/197446
"""


## Note from S0AndS0; repeated `new_doc` __will__ cause all manor of headaches
#def import_all_pngs_as_layers(new_doc, new_doc, path):
def import_all_pngs_as_layers(new_doc, path):
    """
    # Warning: this function is missing from current version of the posted question
    """
    pass


def create_named_group(doc, layer_set, under = ''):
    """
    Create a New LayerSet (aka Group) in the Photoshop document (doc).

    ## Arguments

    - doc (obj): The Photoshop Document Instance
    - under (obj): The Group Object Instance
    (e.g. if you want a subgroup under Lights then give that
    object as a under name)
    - layer_set (str): The name of the new Layer Set

    ## Returns: new_layer_set (obj): The LayerSet (Group) Object
    """
    if not under:  # add a top level group
        new_layer_set = doc.layerSets.Add()
    else:          # add subgroup
        new_layer_set = under.LayerSets.Add()

    new_layer_set.name = layer_set
    return new_layer_set


def paste_file_as_linked_layer(path, psApp):
    """
    Import a file as a Photoshop (smart) linked layer

    ## Arguments

    - path (str): The exact path of the image including extension
    - psApp (object): an instance of `ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')`

    ## Returns: whatever execute action returns (TBC)
    """
    idPlc = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Plc ')

    desc11 = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.ActionDescriptor')
    idIdnt = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Idnt')
    desc11.putInteger(idIdnt, 2)

    # Open the file (path)
    idnull = psApp.charIDToTypeID('null')
    desc11.putPath(idnull, path)

    # set its type as a linked payer
    idLnkd = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Lnkd')
    desc11.putBoolean(idLnkd, True)

    idFTcs = psApp.charIDToTypeID('FTcs')
    idQCSt = psApp.charIDToTypeID('QCSt')
    idQcsa = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Qcsa')
    desc11.putEnumerated(idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa)

    idOfst = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Ofst')
    desc12 = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.ActionDescriptor')
    idHrzn = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Hrzn')
    idRlt = psApp.charIDToTypeID('#Rlt')
    desc12.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idRlt, 0)
    idVrtc = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Vrtc')
    idRlt = psApp.charIDToTypeID('#Rlt')
    desc12.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idRlt, 0)
    idOfst = psApp.charIDToTypeID('Ofst')
    # put the object in an offset space of 0,0
    desc11.putObject(idOfst, idOfst, desc12)

    # _`return`_ of this function is placement of the linked layer
    f = psApp.executeAction(idPlc, desc11, 3)


def create_layer_from_file(doc, layer_name, layer_set, path, psApp):
    """
    Create new Layer from File nested under a LayerSet

    ## Arguments

    - doc (obj): The working Photoshop file
    - layer_name (str): The given name for the Layer
    - layer_set (obj): the LayerSet object that the Layer is nested under
    - path (str): the full Path of the file (including the extension)
    - psApp (object): an instance of `ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')`

    ## Returns: `layer`, an instance of `layer_set.artLayers.Add()`
    """
    psApp.activeDocument = doc
    layer = layer_set.artLayers.Add()
    layer.name = layer_name  # Rename Layer
    doc.activeLayer = layer  # Select Layer

    paste_file_as_linked_layer(os.path.realpath(path).replace('\\', '/'), psApp)

    return layer


def scrubbed_dirname(path):
    """
    ## Returns: path with any `.\\` removed
    """
    ## Note from S0AndS0; careful with writing code like this,
    ##  it can _spaghettify_ a code-base to incomprehensible levels.
    ##  Generally this is a sign that there is something that could
    ##  be done better with whatever is using functions like these.
    ##  Or in other-words, consider Ctrl^f "scrubbed_dirname" to be
    ##  a _highlighter_ for places that code may be getting _hairy_.
    ##  However, this is a balance of what is worth the time as well
    ##  as how far feature-creep plans to take this project.
    return os.path.dirname(path).replace('.\\', '')


def notice(msg, verbosity = 0, *f_list, **f_kwargs):
    """
    Prints formatted notices if `--verbosity` is greater than `0`

    ## Arguments

    - msg (str): The string to print, possibly with formatting
    - f_list (list): A list of arguments to pass to `format()`
    - f_kwargs (dict): Key word arguments to pass to `format()`

    ## Returns: None
    """
    ## Note from S0AndS0; when ya get to the point that adding
    ##  checks for other levels of verbosity, or maybe are considering
    ##  passing something like `v_threshold` and `v_current`, it might
    ##  be better to look for libraries that better express such intent.
    if verbosity <= 0:
        return

    if f_list and f_kwargs:
        print(msg.format(*f_list, **f_kwargs))
    elif f_list:
        print(msg.format(*f_list))
    elif f_kwargs:
        print(msg.format(**f_kwargs))
    else:
        print(msg)
```

As noted the `import_all_pngs_as_layers` function was missing from your question, not sure what it's *special sauce* is but that's okay as my internal parser is more tolerant than Python's. If this omission was intentional I'd advise editing in a real `__license__` reference that expresses your views on edits, use, etc. instead of keeping the *herbs-n-spices* a secret.

The `paste_file_as_linked_layer` and `create_layer_from_file` functions received edits to allow for passing about `psApp`, I get that this is not ideal but more on that later.

The `scrubbed_dirname` is the convenience function that I commented about earlier, and much like the above code's comment-block states, this is something to be very careful with! These kinds of functions can be much like tribbles, one or two isn't too bad but given time and feature-creep maneuvering through a code-base can become a slog.

The `notice` function is another example of a convenience function that replaces the commented `print()` statements with something that outputs conditionally. But like the commented block states, it's probably a good idea to look into a library if there's more features wanted out of something like that. I didn't because I'm not about to assume you'll want to (if allowed) *`pip install something`* just to use my suggestions, that and `notice`'ll show some *fancy* argument passing in the next code block.

I may have messed-up your documentation styling @wizofe (mainly because I use MarkDown just about everywhere), so my apologies on that point. And except for otherwise commented within the code-blocks you've done very well in dividing up portions of the problem space into manageable chunks. Not a whole lot of *ground-breaking* I can do in other-words.

---

#### `png_to_photoshop.py`

> Much like some of those *pocket monsters*, pressing <kbd>b</kbd> will cancel this *evolution*...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import argparse
import comtypes.client as ct
import warnings

from textwrap import dedent
from utils_photoshop import (
    create_layer_from_file,
    create_named_group,
    import_all_pngs_as_layers,
    notice,
    paste_file_as_linked_layer,
    scrubbed_dirname)


#
# _Boilerplate stuff_
#
__description__ = """
This script recursively traverses folder structure starting with given path and creates;

- Photoshop groups named as each sub-directory, within which are

    - all the png files linked to layers and name accordingly

> Sub-directories are treated similarly if found
"""

__license__ = """
See selection from author of question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/219028/197446
"""

__examples__ = """
Add PNG files from: /home/bill/Pictures/funny-cats/

    png_to_photoshop.py --basedir /home/bill/Pictures/funny-cats/\\
     --img_ext png\\
     --misc_dir YarnCollection\\
     --ignored_dirs YarnCollection Unicorns\\
     --layers_group costumed surprised adorbs\\
     --verbosity 9000
"""

__author__ = ('wizofe', 'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/199289/wizofe')

## Note to editors, please add yourself to the following
__editors__ = [
    ('S0AndS0', 'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/197446/s0ands0'),
]

## Note from S0AndS0; you will usually see the reverse of the following
##  at the bottom of files that maybe run or imported, in this case I am
##  being explicit as to how this file may be used without modification.
if __name__ != '__main__':
    raise NotImplementedError("Try running as a script, eg. python file-name.py --help")


#
# Parse the command line arguments into an `args_dict`
#
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = __description__, epilog = __examples__, allow_abbrev = False)
## Example of adding command-line argument
# parser.add_argument('--foo', default = 'Fooed', type = str, help = 'Foo is defaulted to -> %(default)s')

parser.add_argument('--about', action = 'store_true', help = 'Prints info about this script and exits')
parser.add_argument('--license', action = 'store_true', help = 'Prints script license and exits')

parser.add_argument('--verbosity',
                    type = int,
                    default = 0,
                    help = "How verbose to be during execution, default %(default)s")

parser.add_argument('--img_ext',
                    default = 'png',
                    help = "Image extension to import into Photoshop with this script, default %(default)s")

parser.add_argument('--base_dir',
                    required = True,
                    help = 'Base directory to recursively parse for PNG files into Photoshop layers')

parser.add_argument('--misc_dir',
                    required = True,
                    help = 'Base directory to recursively parse for PNG files into Photoshop layers')

parser.add_argument('--ignored_dirs',
                    nargs='+',
                    default = ['Misc', 'Wheel_Merged'],
                    help = "List of sub-directory names to ignore while _walking_ base_dir, default %(default)s")

## Note from S0AndS0; ya may want to play with the following `help`
##  to get output of `script-name.py --help` looking more acceptable.
parser.add_argument('--layers_group',
                    nargs='+',
                    default = ['Body_Side', 'Grille'],
                    help = textwrap.dedent("""
                        List of association names between file names, and Photoshop sub-groups, default %(default)s.

                        For example "{name}_01, 22_{name}, {name}0" could be grouped to "{name}",
                        via something like...

                            script-name.py --layers_group {name}
                    """.format(name = 'Grille')))

args_dict = vars(parser.parse_args())


#
# Ways to prematurely exit from script, note `--help` takes care of itself
#
if args_dict['license']:
    print(__license__)
    sys.exit()


if args_dict['about']:
    message = """
    This script and related code was brought to you by

    Author: {name} of {url}
    """.format(name = __author__[0], url = __author__[1])

    if __editors__:
        message += '\n\n\tand...\n'
    for name, url in __editors__:
        message += "\t{name} -> {url}".format(**{'name': name, 'url': url})

    print(dedent(message))
    sys.exit()


## Note from S0AndS0; I moved the following two assignments and
##  modified the `paste_file_as_linked_layer` and `create_layer_from_file`
##  functions to pass `psApp` about, because I figure a future self
##  or reader will want to customize it a bit more. This is less than
##  ideal, so see the posted notes for some thoughts on the future.
psApp = ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application')
new_doc = psApp.Documents.Add(600, 800, 72, 'new-psb-test', 2, 1, 1)

# Import layers from Misc as Background and Shadow
misc_path = os.path.join(args_dict['base_dir'], args_dict['misc_dir'])
os.chdir(misc_path)
import_all_pngs_as_layers(new_doc = new_doc, path = misc_path)
os.chdir(args_dict['base_dir'])  # Revert the working path

duplicate = False
subdir = False
img_ext = ".{ext}".format(ext = args_dict['img_ext'])


for root, dd, ff in os.walk(args_dict['base_dir']):
    ## Note from S0AndS0; where is `path` being used?
    ##  Or is this _zombie_/_vestigial_ code?
    path = root.split(os.sep)

    root_dir_basename = os.path.basename(root)
    if root_dir_basename == '.':  # ignore parent
        pass

    if scrubbed_dirname(root) in args_dict['ignored_dirs']:
        pass

    if not os.path.dirname(root) == '.' and not scrubbed_dirname(root) in args_dict['ignored_dirs']:
        notice(msg = "I am a subdir {} of the dir {}",
               verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
               root_dir_basename,
               scrubbed_dirname(root))
        create_named_group(
            doc = new_doc,
            layer_set = root_dir_basename,
            under = new_doc.LayerSets(scrubbed_dirname(root)))
    elif not root_dir_basename in args_dict['ignored_dirs']:
        notice(msg = "Creating TOP LEVEL layer group {name}",
               verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
               name = root_dir_basename)
        create_named_group(
            doc = new_doc,
            layer_set = root_dir_basename)
    else:  # Uncaught state!
        warnings.warn("\n".join([
            'How did I get here?',
            "\tWhat did you give me?",
            "\t... uh-oh, I think I will pass on these questions and current state with...",
            "\troot_dir_basename -> {path}".format(path = root_dir_basename),
        ]))
        pass

    ## Note from S0AndS0; the following might be better if higher
    ##  up in the execution stack of for loop, unless there is a
    ##  reason to have `create_named_group` fire on empty `ff`
    if len(ff) <= 0:
        pass

    for filename in ff:
        if not filename.endswith(img_ext):
            pass

        for item in args_dict['layers_group']:
            notice(msg = "{item} in {filename}",
                   verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
                   item = item,
                   filename = filename)
            if item in filename:
                notice(msg = "Creating group {group} to place layer {layer} within folder {folder}",
                       verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
                       group = item,
                       layer = filename,
                       folder = root_dir_basename)
                os.chdir(os.path.realpath(root))

                try:
                    new_doc.LayerSets(root_dir_basename).LayerSets(item)
                except:
                    named_group = create_named_group(
                        doc = new_doc,
                        layer_set = item,
                        under = new_doc.LayerSets(root_dir_basename))
                    create_layer_from_file(
                        doc = new_doc,
                        layer_name = filename,
                        layer_set = named_group,
                        path = os.path.realpath(filename),
                        psApp = psApp)
                else:
                    notice(msg = new_doc.LayerSets(root_dir_basename), verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'])
                    create_layer_from_file(
                        doc = new_doc,
                        layer_name = filename,
                        layer_set = new_doc.LayerSets(root_dir_basename).LayerSets(item),
                        path = os.path.realpath(filename),
                        psApp = psApp)

                duplicate = True
                os.chdir(args_dict['base_dir'])

        if duplicate:
            duplicate = False
            pass

        if root_dir_basename in args_dict['ignored_dirs'] or scrubbed_dirname(root) in args_dict['ignored_dirs']:
            pass

        os.chdir(os.path.realpath(root))
        notice(msg = "Resting files imported as layers {layer} under {folder}",
               verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
               layer = filename,
               folder = root_dir_basename)

        if not os.path.dirname(root) == '.':
            notice(msg = "layer {layer} on main group {m_group} on group {group}",
                   verbosity = args_dict['verbosity'],
                   layer = filename,
                   m_group = os.path.dirname(root).replace('.\\', ''),
                   group = root_dir_basename)
            create_layer_from_file(
                doc = new_doc,
                layer_name = filename,
                layer_set = new_doc.LayerSets(scrubbed_dirname(root)).LayerSets(root_dir_basename),
                path = os.path.realpath(filename),
                psApp = psApp)
        else:
            create_layer_from_file(
                doc = new_doc,
                layer_name = filename,
                layer_set = new_doc.LayerSets[root_dir_basename],
                path = os.path.realpath(filename),
                psApp = psApp)

            os.chdir(args_dict['base_dir'])
```

There'll be somethings that'll likely look familiar in the above code block, and some things that are *`diff`erent*; I'll encourage readers to pull-out interesting bits and try'em in *scriptlets* because as it is neither the question's code nor what I've so far posted will function.

If there are questions on why I've written some-thing some-way, feel free to ask in the comments. Basically all I've added so far is some `argparse` tricks and re-factored your code to be a little less [*`cyclomaticly complex`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) (it's still a bit high as it is), really you where on the *right track* @wizofe with using `pass` often and I've just tried to follow along with it.

> The observant readers may also be noting my use of quotes, while Python doesn't care one way or another on *`'some string'`* vs *`"some string"`*, I personally find it easier to read *moons later* when there's consistent use that means something about the contents. In this case single-quotes don't have anything *fancy* going on where as double quotes may have formatting stuffed in somewhere.

---

Moving on to what could be further improved, and on track with what I was commenting earlier about and intermediate structure for organizing some of this. Some of these `for` loops might be easier to expand upon as [`Iterator`s](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), eg...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import argparse
import comtypes.client as ct
import warnings

from textwrap import dedent
from utils_photoshop import (
    create_layer_from_file,
    create_named_group,
    import_all_pngs_as_layers,
    notice,
    paste_file_as_linked_layer,
    scrubbed_dirname)

from collections import Iterator


class DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger(Dict, Iterator):
    """
    DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger is a hybrid class between a `dict`ionary and `Iterator`

    After modifications your _mileage_ may be improved
    """

    def __init__(base_dir, misc_dir, layers_group, ignored_dirs, verbosity = 0, **kwargs):
        super(DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update({
            'base_dir': base_dir,
            'misc_dir': misc_dir,
            'layers_group': layers_group,
            'ignored_dirs': ignored_dirs,
            'verbosity': verbosity},
            'dir_steps': os.walk(base_dir),
            'duplicate': False,
            'subdir': False,
            'grouped_layers': {},
            'psApp': ct.CreateObject('Photoshop.Application'),
            'misc_path': os.path.join(base_dir, misc_dir))

        os.chdir(self['misc_path'])
        self.update(new_doc = self['psApp'].Documents.Add(600, 800, 72, 'new-psb-test', 2, 1, 1))
        self.update(misc_layers = import_all_pngs_as_layers(new_doc = self['new_doc'], path = self['misc_path']))
        # Revert the working path
        os.chdir(self['base_dir'])

        self.update()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            root, dd, ff = self['dir_steps'].next()
        except (StopIteration):
            self.throw(GeneratorExit)

        if scrubbed_dirname(root) in self['ignored_dirs']:
            pass

        root_dir_basename = os.path.basename(root)
        if root_dir_basename == '.':  # ignore parent
            pass

        ## ... do more stuff before returning `self`

        return self

    #
    # Python 2/3 compatibility stuff
    #

    def throw(self, type = None, traceback = None):
        raise StopIteration

    __next__ = next
```

... which may give ya the controls to *flatten* things into *`categories`* (first sub-directory name, or similar) via something like *`self['categories'].update(hash_path: container_object)`* or *`self['categories'].append(container_object)`*

In the future you might want to consider pulling some of the functions from `utils_photoshop/__init__.py` into the `DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger` `class`. Namely those that I modified to pass `psApp` about, instead maybe hav'em use `self['psApp']`.

Incorporating portions of pre-existing code from the main `for` loop into the suggested *iterator* will require a little editing, eg. *`...doc = new_doc,...`* would become *`...doc = self['new_doc'],...`*, and later maybe removed if things like the `create_layer_from_file` function are pulled into the `class`. That last state might begin to look something like...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

## ... other import and initialization stuff

class DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger(Dict, Iterator):

    # ... things like __init__ above

    def create_named_group(self, layer_set, under = ''):
        """
        Create a New LayerSet (aka Group) in the Photoshop document (self['new_doc']).

        ## Arguments

        - layer_set (str): The name of the new Layer Set
        - under (obj): The Group Object Instance, optional

        ## Returns: new_layer_set (obj): The LayerSet (Group) Object
        """
        if not under:  # add a top level group
            new_layer_set = self['new_doc'].layerSets.Add()
        else:          # add subgroup
            new_layer_set = under.LayerSets.Add()

        new_layer_set.name = layer_set
        return new_layer_set

    def next(self):
        try:
            root, dd, ff = self['dir_steps'].next()
        except (StopIteration):
            self.throw(GeneratorExit)

        root_dir_basename = os.path.basename(root)
        if root_dir_basename == '.':  # ignore parent
            pass

        if scrubbed_dirname(root) in self['ignored_dirs']:
            pass

        if not os.path.dirname(root) == '.' and not scrubbed_dirname(root) in self['ignored_dirs']:
            notice(msg = "Searching sub-directory {subdir} of the directory {directory}",
                   verbosity = self['verbosity'],
                   subdir = oot_dir_basename,
                   directory = scrubbed_dirname(root))
            self.create_named_group(
                layer_set = root_dir_basename,
                under = self['new_doc'].LayerSets(scrubbed_dirname(root)))

        ## ... do more stuff before returning `self`

        return self

    ## ... other class stuff


if __name__ == __main__:
    import argparse

    #
    # Parse the command line arguments into an `args_dict`
    #
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = __description__, epilog = __examples__, allow_abbrev = False)
    # parser.add_argument('--foo', default = 'Fooed', type = str, help = "Foo is defaulted to -> %(default)s")

    ## ... more argparsy goodness

    args_dict = vars(parser.parse_args())


    #
    # Initialize the DirWalker
    #
    f_line = ".-.".join('_' for _ in range(9))
    dir_walker = DirWalker_PhotoshopRanger(**args_dict)

    for i, state in enumerate(dir_walker):
        notice(msg = "{f_line}\n{count}".format(f_line = f_line, count = i),
               verbosity = 9001)
        for k, v in state.items():
            notice(msg = "{key} -> {value}".format(key = k, value = v),
                   verbosity = 9002)

        notice(msg = "{f_line}".format(f_line = f_line), verbosity = 9001)
```

If written carefully these structures can be very performant on memory use and other system resources. Though yet again I'll warn that a code-base can get *hairy* with'em, in different ways than with convenience functions, but with very similar effect. Additionally it maybe of use to know that functions that use `yield` operate very similarly to iterators, and be called *`generators`*, eg...

```py
def range_summinator(start, end):
    increment = 1
    if end < start:
        increment = -1

    while start != end:
        start += increment

        yield start


r = range_summinator(0, 2)
r.next()  # -> 1
r.next()  # -> 2
r.next()
#   Traceback (most recent call last):
#     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   StopIteration
```

Okay I think this is a good pausing point to mull things over, and perhaps find bugs within my own suggestions, gotta say it was kinda a challenge without testing it in it's entirety. I may update this as thoughts percolate, and if comments/questions are posted.

---

Resources useful in writing (and maybe expanding upon) above are not limited to the following;

- [how-to-pass-and-parse-a-list-of-strings-from-command-line-with-argparse-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786174/how-to-pass-and-parse-a-list-of-strings-from-command-line-with-argparse-argument) Q&A from StackOverflow
- [simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results) Q&A from StackOverflow
- [raise-warning-in-python-without-interrupting-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891804/raise-warning-in-python-without-interrupting-program) Q&A from StackOverflow
- [terminating-a-python-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script) Q&A from StackOverflow
- [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) Python documentation
- [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog) Python documentation
- [`Iterator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) Python documentation
- [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) Python documentation